# kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_TrimDurationAtStart error

Tags: avfoundation, mp4, cmsamplebuffer

Getting an error when trying to convert a video recorded from camera or picked from gallery:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVAssetWriterInput appendSampleBuffer:] 
Cannot append sample buffer: First input buffer must have an appropriate kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_TrimDurationAtStart since the codec has encoder delay'`

This is discussed here: [CMSampleBufferRef kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_TrimDurationAtStart crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35425951/cmsamplebufferref-kcmsamplebufferattachmentkey-trimdurationatstart-crash)

But no resolution was reached.

Here is my code:

```
[self.audioInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:self.audioQueue usingBlock:^{
        CMSampleBufferRef buffer;
        LIMTAssetFileWriter * __strong strongSelf = weakSelf;
        while (strongSelf.audioInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData) {
            LIMTPayload *payload = [strongSelf.cache dequeuePayloadForType:LIMTPayloadTypeAudio];
            buffer = payload.getCMSampleBuffer;
            if (buffer) {
                if (!strongSelf.sessionStarted) {
                    [strongSelf.assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(buffer)];
                    strongSelf.sessionStarted = YES;
                }
                [strongSelf.audioInput appendSampleBuffer:buffer];
                [LIMTLogger.sharedLogger logInfo:@"Audio buffer appended"];
                CFRelease(buffer);
                buffer = NULL;
            } else if ([strongSelf.cache statusForType:kCMMediaType_Audio] == LIMTCacheStatusCompleted) {
                [strongSelf.audioInput markAsFinished];
                [LIMTLogger.sharedLogger logInfo:@"Audio complete"];
                dispatch_group_leave(strongSelf.dispatchGroup);
                break;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }];
```

Error is happening here: `[strongSelf.audioInput appendSampleBuffer:buffer];`

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Yes .. read this for more detail https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/QTFFAppenG/QTFFAppenG.html